# Opening an OS X disk image with a launchd agent while the display is sleeping

Tags: macos, unix, launchd

I created a `launchd` agent which opens a non-password-protected sparse disk image (and mounts its solitary volume) daily at 2:45AM in preparation for backup software to write to the volume. The `launchd` agent's plist file is saved in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`. Here are the plist file's parameters:

```
Label: my.DiskImageOpener
KeepAlive: NO
RunAtLoad: NO
StartCalendar:
    Hour: 2
    Minute: 45
ProgramArguments:
    hdiutil
    attach
    /path/to/MyDiskImage.sparseimage
```

As long as the computer's display is awake, the agent works as advertised, opening the disk image and mounting its volume at the time specified in the launch agent. On the other hand, if the display is asleep at the time specified in the launch agent, the disk image fails to open until the display is awoken from sleep (even if that is several hours later), at which point the disk image immediately opens and mounts its volume. The same phenomenon happens if I replace the `hdiutil attacj /path/to/MyDiskImage.sparseimage` command with `open /path/to/MyDiskImage.sparseimage`, or place the command in a separate executable shell script that the launch agent executes.

How can I get the launch agent to open the disk image and mount its volume when the display is asleep?

I am using a MacBook Pro laptop running OS X 10.8.2 Mountain Lion. Thank you for any assistance with this problem.

Comment: Is the entire computer asleep, or just the display? If the computer's asleep, no processing will happen (launchd jobs, backups, etc). (OK, there's an exception: [Power Nap, aka Dark Wake](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5394).)

Comment: Because this is such a deeply MacOS-specific question, why might have better luck with http://apple.stackexchange.com/ instead. Otherwise, I would suggest replacing `ProgramArguments` with a shell script that echos some debugging lines (e.g. `echo about to start hdiutil at $(date)`) and then invokes `hdiutil`. That would at least tell you if `hdiutil` is hanging or if instead the launch agent is not getting invoked at all.

Comment: (1) Just the display is asleep. The computer is awake. So it has something to do with the display being asleep. (2) I tried an `echo $(date)` debugging command (as a separate executable shell script), and the launch agent executed it properly even with the display asleep. Therefore, it would appear to be a problem with a launch agent trying to open a disk image with the display asleep. Thank you for these two helpful suggestions. I'm happy to submit this to apple.stackexchange.com, as you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I stumbled on the solution. As long as I keep the computer set to never sleep in the Energy Saver preference pane, then even if the display is asleep and/or the hard drive is set to sleep when possible, then the launch agent runs successfully, opening the disk image and mounting the volume. Inexplicably, if the computer is set to any setting other than never to sleep (even though it may in fact be awake), the launch agent fails.